# What kind of check does DirectoryQ exactly perform?

Tags: files-and-directories

I'm using *Mathematica* 9.0.1 on Windows XP and my drive letters are assigned as follows: `C:` and `D:` are hard local disks, while `E:` is assigned to some removable media. Now, the situation is as follows

```
DirectoryQ[# <> ":\\"] & /@ {"c", "d", "e"}
```

returns `{True,True,True}`, even when an optical disk isn't in the drive.

To outflank the problem I use a `directoryQ` function, defined in the code below.

However, it obviously fails against a full hard disk or when I don't have write access. Therefore, I' m wondering about the kind of check `DirectoryQ` basically performs. Is there a better solution to fix the problem?

```
   directoryQ[unit_]:=Module[
       {root,file,ret},
       ret=False;
       root=unit<>":\\";
       file = FileNameJoin[{root, "testFile.txt"}];
       If[
         DirectoryQ[root],
         Quiet[Export[file,"test","Text"]];
         If[
           FileExistsQ[file],
           DeleteFile[file];
           ret=True
         ];
       ];
       Return[ret];
];

directoryQ["c"]
directoryQ["e"]
```

Comment: I don't have windows, but I like this question. I did some slight edits on your text to make it more conform with the site. What I can tell you from Linux, Unix and Mac is that disks or USB drives are always *mounted to an existing directory* (usually, some subfolder is created). Even my second (built-in) hard drive has a fixed mountpoint which is `/home`, a directory. It doesn't matter whether the hard disk is there or not.

Comment: Is the problem just that `DirectoryQ` returns the right answer except in the one case that its argument is a root directory of a drive that isn't mounted?  In that case, you could try verifying the result by (1) checking if the path is a root directory (maybe using `FileNameSplit`?), then (2) calling `SetDirectory` or `FileExistsQ` to see if you can actually go there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since Mathematica is written in the C programming language, it is likely that any file-system status operation is doing nothing more than calling C's built-in functions.  In this case, that would be `stat`.

So let's test what `stat` does on Windows.  According to the C language documentation, `stat` is given the name of something in the file system, and returns a C structure whose fields describe the properties of that thing.  In particular, the `st_mode` field seems relevant:

> **st_mode**: Bit mask for file-mode information. The _S_IFDIR bit is set if path specifies a directory; the _S_IFREG bit is set if path specifies an ordinary file or a device. User read/write bits are set according to the file's permission mode; user execute bits are set according to the filename extension.

I wrote a simple test program in Microsoft Visual C that tests the `stat` function.  Drive C: is my Windows system drive; drive E: is my DVD drive, which currently doesn't have anything in it.  Here's what I found:

```
stat("C:\\WINDOWS") returns success and sets _S_IFDIR
stat("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\NOTEPAD.EXE") returns success and does not set _S_IFDIR
stat("C:\\") returns success and sets _S_IFDIR
stat("E:\\") returns success and sets _S_IFDIR
stat("W:\\") returns failure
```

So we can conclude from this that Windows, or at least the `stat` function on Windows, considers empty DVD drives to be "there."  I also have a flash memory stick that I can plug into a USB slot, which I have mapped to drive W, but that "isn't there" when it's unplugged.

This is consistent with what Windows Explorer shows me when I click on "My Computer".  I see drive C: with a name, and I see drive E:, even though I get an error message when I double-click on it.  I don't see drive W: (my flash memory stick) after I pulled it out of the socket.  So Windows does consider an empty DVD drive to be present, which is probably why `stat` says it's a valid directory.

I have no idea how to find out whether a DVD drive is full or empty in C, much less in Mathematica.  But at least we can see the core of the problem.

Comment: I really like your detailed answers and extensive knowledge of low-level I/O. +1

Comment: I fully agree with halirutan.  I only wish you posted more often. :-)

Comment: Using `strace`, I can confirm that on Linux at least, DirectoryQ does simply `stat` the input.

Comment: Admirable answer ! Please, can you share your test program's source code ?

Answer (score 7):

This response shows how to obtain more detailed information about directories (and files) using JLink, NETLink and the Win32 API.  Such information can be used to determine if a device is offline, non-writable, etc.  The various methods differ in how much information they return.

**JLink**

The Java 6 [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#method_summary) class can be used to retrieve many file system attributes on any operating system supported by Mathematica:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];

javaFileAttributes[path_String] :=
  JavaBlock @ Module[{p, file = JavaNew["java.io.File", path]}
  , Cases[{canExecute, canRead, canWrite, exists, isDirectory, isFile, isHidden}
    , p_ /; file@p[]
    ]
  ]
```

Example use (`d:\` is an offline drive):

```
Table[{p, javaFileAttributes@p}
, {p, {"c:\\", "d:\\", "c:\\temp", "c:\\pagefile.sys", "c:\\bootsect.bak"}}
] // Grid

(*
c:\             {canExecute,canRead,canWrite,exists,isDirectory,isHidden}
d:\             {}
c:\temp         {canExecute,canRead,canWrite,exists,isDirectory}
c:\pagefile.sys {exists,isFile}
c:\bootsect.bak {canExecute,canRead,exists,isFile,isHidden}
*)
```

**NETLink**

On Windows, or a system running Mono, we can perform a similar operation using the .NET method [File.GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];

LoadNETType["System.IO.File", AllowShortContext -> False];
LoadNETType["System.IO.FileAttributes", AllowShortContext -> False];

dotNetException[] := dotNetException[GetNETException[]]
dotNetException[e_] := Module[{i = e@InnerException[]}, dotNetException[i] /; i =!= Null]
dotNetException[e_] := $Failed@#&[e@Message // StringTrim]

dotNetFileAttributes[path_String] :=
  NETBlock @ Module[{p, file = Quiet@System`IO`File`GetAttributes[path]}
  , file /.
    { f_?NETObjectQ :> StringSplit[f@ToString[], (Whitespace|",")..]
    , $Failed :> dotNetException[]
    }
  ]
```

Example use (`d:\` is an offline drive):

```
Table[{p, dotNetFileAttributes@p}
, {p, {"c:\\", "d:\\", "c:\\temp", "c:\\pagefile.sys", "c:\\bootsect.bak"}}
] // Grid

(*
c:\             {Hidden,System,Directory}
d:\             $Failed[The device is not ready.]
c:\temp         {Directory}
c:\pagefile.sys {Hidden,System,Archive}
c:\bootsect.bak {ReadOnly,Hidden,System,Archive}
*)
```

**Win32 API through NETLink**

On Windows, we can access the Windows API function [GetFileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) through NETLink:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[]

kernel32GetLastError =
  DefineDLLFunction["GetLastError", "kernel32.dll", "DWORD", {}];

kernel32GetFileAttributes =
  DefineDLLFunction["GetFileAttributes", "kernel32.dll", "DWORD", {"string"}];

windowsError[] :=
  kernel32GetLastError[] /.
    { 2 -> "FILE_NOT_FOUND", 3 -> "PATH_NOT_FOUND", 5 -> "ACCESS_DENIED"
    , 15 -> "INVALID_DRIVE", 21 -> "NOT_READY", 32 -> "SHARING_VIOLATION"
    , n_ :> "Error code: "~~ToString[n]
    }

$fileAttributes =
 { {"ARCHIVE", 32}, {"COMPRESSED", 2048}, {"DEVICE", 64}, {"DIRECTORY", 16}
 , {"ENCRYPTED", 16384}, {"HIDDEN", 2}, {"INTEGRITY_STREAM", 32768}
 , {"NORMAL", 128}, {"NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED", 8192}, {"NO_SCRUB_DATA", 131072}
 , {"OFFLINE", 4096}, {"READONLY", 1}, {"REPARSE_POINT", 1024}, {"SPARSE_FILE", 512}
 , {"SYSTEM", 4}, {"TEMPORARY", 256}, {"VIRTUAL", 65536}
 };

windowsFileAttributes[path_String] :=
  kernel32GetFileAttributes[path] /.
    { -1 :> { $Failed@#&@windowsError[] }
        , a_ :> Cases[$fileAttributes, {n_, v_} /; BitAnd[v, a] != 0 :> n]
    }
```

Example use (`d:\` is an offline drive):

```
Table[{p, windowsFileAttributes@p}
, {p, {"c:\\", "d:\\", "c:\\temp", "c:\\pagefile.sys", "c:\\bootsect.bak"}}
] // Grid

(*
    c:\             {DIRECTORY,HIDDEN,SYSTEM}
    d:\             {$Failed[NOT_READY]}
    c:\temp         {DIRECTORY}
    c:\pagefile.sys {$Failed[SHARING_VIOLATION]}
    c:\bootsect.bak {ARCHIVE,HIDDEN,READONLY,SYSTEM}
*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm extremely grateful to  halirutan for repairing my message !
I will try to bother as less I can.

Following librik's guidance I wrote two functions:

```
directoryQversionA[unit_]:=Module[
{root,file,ret},
   ret=True;
   root=unit<>":\\";
   Quiet[Check[SetDirectory[root],ret=False]];
Return[ret];
];

directoryQversionB[unit_]:=Module[
{root,file,ret},ret=False;
   root=unit<>":\\";
   ret=FileExistsQ[root];
   Return[ret];
];
```

This works as expected

```
directoryQversionA/@{"c","z"}
directoryQversionB/@{"c","z"}
```

Regarding the removable media, using

```
directoryQversionA["e"]
directoryQversionB["e"]
```

I get True when a support is inside and False when it isn't.

As far as I can see,the problem who drove me to ask the question is solved on my operating system: I will check on more recent versions.