# how can I manage the characters encoding of retun value from FetchURLWithHeaders?

Tags: character-encoding

I have retrieved a file from a web server by means of the FetchURLWithHeaders function.

The retun value from FetchURLWithHeaders should contains the substring

SCHØNHEYDER

but instead I find

SCH����NHEYDER

and

```
ToCharacterCode /@ Characters["SCH����NHEYDER"]
```

gives

{{83}, {67}, {72}, {65533}, {65533}, {65533}, {65533}, {78}, {72}, {69}, {89}, {68}, {69}, {82}}

How can I transform SCH����NHEYDER in SCHØNHEYDER and print in a text file ?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: ``Utilities`URLTools`FetchURLWithHeaders`` is an older, undocumented function. Have you tried `URLFetch` instead? The "SCH����NHEYDER" string can not be turn into the original as the � character (65533) is used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode. So, the original value is lost.

Comment: You could try `URLFetch` with the option `"Headers" -> {"Content-Type" -> "text/html;charset=utf-8"}`. Could you provide an example URL to test with?

Comment: I have Mathematica 8.0.0.1; I can count only on the versions of functions provided there.
-1-
I get:
    FetchURL // Options
    {FileFilters -> {{".gz", UncompressGZIPFile}},  "ServerAuthentication" -> Automatic, "Timeout" -> Automatic,  "RequestMethod" -> "GET", "RequestParameters" -> {},  "RequestHeaderFields" -> {}}

    FetchURLWithHeaders // Options
    {}
-2-
FetchURLWithHeaders accepts option "Headers" but return value is unchanged.
-3-
FetchURLWithHeaders calls FetchURLInternal. Can I make FetchURLInternal public by means of 
FetchURLInternal::usage="something" and adapt it ?

Comment: If you're targeting a specific version you should mention that in the question. Anyway, could you try FetchURL with its option "RequestHeaderFields" set to the value mentioned above for "Headers"? Also, still waiting for an example URL.

Comment: In an [earlier question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45793/what-kind-of-check-does-directoryq-exactly-perform) you mention using version 9. How come you're using v8 now?

Comment: Please forgive: 
1. I didn't think it was a version-conditioned issue 
2. I can't provide the exact url, but  it looks like http://someserver/get.php?=somestring.

In Mathematica 8.0.1.0 :
1. "URLFetch" doesn't exist. 
2.
    FetchURL[url,fileName,"RequestHeaderFields"->{"Content-Type"->"text/html;charset=utf-8"}]

returns only fileName itself.

Comment: I use for each project the version found installed on an PC (in the college's lab) unoccupied when it starts.

At present moment there are no license avaible other than 8.

Comment: I asked for the URL (or an equivalent one) in question so that I could test the character encoding. A generic URL won't help in this.

Comment: I'm sorry but the url isn't in public domain. Anyway, I'm extremely grateful for your kind replies and I found them really useful. May I receive further hints about the character encoding tests you suggest to perform, please ? May be we can examine to subject, in its general form, starting from public urls ...