# Importing files into mathematica from flashdrive

Tags: import

I don't know why I can't get my files to import from my flashdrive into my notebook.

I have .mat files and .cvs files.

I've tried this

```
Import["/LocalDisk(E:)/MOptics/imagedata1.mat"]
```

and this

```
Import["/Computer/LocalDisk(E:)/MOptics/imagedata1.mat"]
```

and this

```
Import["/Computer/LocalDisk/MOptics/imagedata1.mat"]
```

and this for the cvs

```
Import["/LocalDisk(E:)/MOptics/sun1.csv"];
```

with the same variations as above.

LocalDisk(E:) is the flashdrive and MOptics is the folder.

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: windows paths look like: "E:\\MOptics\\..." (single  forward slash should work as well )

Comment: Windows. I am working on a school computer so I was trying to import them off a P drive at first which it didn't like either

Comment: "E:\\MOptics\\. didn't work

Comment: What *Mathematica* is this? 10?

Comment: It's mathematia 9

Comment: Try `SetDirectory["E:"]` ( or whatever the drive letter is of course )  , then `FileNames[]`

Comment: Try copying the file to the local harddrive with the Windows Explorer first and report back, if that worked.

Comment: I switched computers and tried again. Got it to work. Thank you!

Comment: overkill, but maybe useful to someone http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45918/2079

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked in my case:

First open a new notebook.

Save it to your flashdrive, into the same folder where your "csv" files are located.

type in:

```
NotebookDirectory[]
```

Out:

```
/Volumes/TRANSCEND/MOptics/
```

Now you know exactly how the filename is represented in your system.
I am on a mac, thats why my filenameSeperators are represented as "/".
Go to your notebook located at your harddrive and type in:

```
dir = "/Volumes/TRANSCEND/MOptics/";
Import[FileNameJoin[{dir,"sun1.csv"}]
```

Its practical to save your SD-directory to a variable and use FileNameJoin. FileNameJoin is OS-independent and uses automatically the correct filenameseparator for your system.

**EDIT:**

completely system-independent solution:

Get a directory list from your folder located at flashdrive:

```
dirList = FileNameSplit[NotebookDirectory[]]
```

Out:

```
{"", "Volumes", "TRANSCEND","MOptics"}
```

Importing a File from hdd:

```
dirList = {"", "Volumes", "TRANSCEND", "MOptics"};
Import[FileNameJoin[Append[dirList, "sun1.csv"]]]
```